# How to create a matrix in python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a matrix: [1, 2, 3] & [4, 5, 6] & [7, 8, 9]. Written down they look like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwEj8.png).

Now, I would like to create this matrix in Python, but I am not sure how to do so.

I think its written like either this:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

Or like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1, 4, 7],
          [2, 5, 8],
          [3, 6, 9]])
```

Which way should I use?

Comment: The answer could be : no matter, depend on how you'll use it. In most case it' no matter you just need to use it the way you have defined it

Comment: Technically it's up to you as long as you keep everything consistent. But if you ever want to get it the other way you can just transpose the matrix.

Comment: The second one is closer to what you asked in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the right answer to this is that, there is none :)

Actually it all depends how do you want that this matrix acts on something.

Multiplying elementwise with another matrix, matrix product or matrix vector product.

Comment: I did some poking around, and I think the matrices I made above are inverses of each other. I think I will be using the first method for now.

Comment: They are the transpose of each other. The inverse would be a different one, as the inverse is caracterized by A.A^-1 = Identity